# Find all possible sums from array while maintaining index association

Tags: php, arrays, sum, combinations

I'm working with some data that provides payment methods accepted as a sum of their numeric values. The payment methods are:

```
2 Visa
4 Mastercard
8 American Express
16 Discover
32 Diners
64 Cash
128 Check
256 Debit
```

So if Visa and Mastercard are accepted, the value would be 6. If Visa, Mastercard and Discover are accepted, it would be 22.

I think one way to deal with this would be to come up with an array of all possible sums, where the sums are the index and the payment methods used to comprise that sum are the array for that index. Ex:

```
$methods = array(
    2 => array(
        2 => 'Visa'
    ),
    4 => array(
        4 => 'Mastercard'
    ),
    6 => array(
        2 => 'Visa',
        4 => 'Mastercard'
    ),
    8 => array(
        8 => 'American Express'
    ),
    10 => array(
        2 => 'Visa',
        8 => 'American Express'
    )
);
```

And so on, and put that into a file to include so then all I have to do is specify $methods[10] and get the array of Visa and Amex.

Another part of me thinks the payment methods themselves could be put into an array, and a formula could be used to do the calculation on the fly. I'd prefer this way if possible, but I can't figure it out. A simple:

```
$methods = paymentMethods(10);
```

How do I solve the problem of only having a sum to work from, and determining what values (payment methods) were used to create that sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should roughly work, I don't have the time to test it myself, don't hesitate to comment if there is an issue (here `$cards` is the array of payment methods at the beginning of your question).

```
<?php

function methods($n) {
    global $cards;
    $k = closest_to($n);
    $r = $n - $k;
    if ($r != 0) {
        return array($k => $cards[$k]) + methods($r);
    } else {
        return array($k => $cards[$k]);
    }
}

function closest_to($n) {
    global $cards;
    $prevK = null;
    foreach ($cards as $k => $v) {
        if ($k > $n) {
            return $prevK;
        }
        $prevK = $k;
    }
    end($cards);
    return key($cards);
}
```

Comment: Your code was the general setup needed and I was able to modify it (edits above) to get it to function, and it seems to work :) Thank you!